# Salt-minion not upgrading

Tags: upgrade, salt-stack

I've a salt-minion who refuses to upgrade.
When I try to update it, apt-get says that it is already the newest version.
Others minions are updating without problems.

I've already tried to uninstall it and reinstall it.

Any hints?

Here follows salt-minion version, apt-get result and os version.
Thank you.

```
root@myserver:~# salt-call --version
salt-call 2016.11.0rc2 (Carbon)

root@myserver:~# apt-get upgrade salt-minion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
salt-minion is already the newest version.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libzmq3 postgresql-contrib
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

root@myserver:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

The result of apt-cache policy is:

```
root@myserver:~# apt-cache policy salt-minion
salt-minion:
  Installed: 2016.11.5+ds-3
  Candidate: 2016.11.5+ds-3
  Version table:
 *** 2016.11.5+ds-3 0
        500 http://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/14.04/amd64/latest/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.17.5+ds-1 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: what is the output of: `apt-cache policy salt-minion` ?

Comment: Hi @gbrandsma, I've added the results from apt-cache policy.

Comment: Ok, your `salt-call --version` should have given the same version number as the `apt-cache policy salt-minion`. I think your system is messed up. I would  remove and reinstall the salt-minion on this specific system. (sorry, I can't help you further right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** `salt-call` command is not a part of the `salt-minion` package. It is a part of the `salt-common` package. You probably have to upgrade this package to fix the problem.

**Some background**:
to find out which command is actually being executed when you run `salt-call` you can use command which:

```
$ which salt-call
/usr/bin/salt-call
```

Now we can find out which package is the one installing `/usr/bin/salt-call` by running:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/salt-call 
salt-common: /usr/bin/salt-call
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. After your suggestion I find the right way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After veryifing that I had different versions of salt components installed (Thank you @alexK), I solved in this way:

- made a backup of my minion settings
- removed salt-* from /usr/local/bin (here I had the older version)
- uninstalled (purged) salt-minion and salt-common
- I issued a "pip uninstall salt"
- I removed the salt repos from /var/lib/apt/lists
- Cleaned the apt-get cache

After this cleaning phase, reinstalling through apt-get didn't work since it kept reinstalling the wrong version.

Adding the ppa:saltstack/salt repo didn't work too.

It only worked installing salt through Salt-Bootstrap.